# Logs in to home page drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have installed the user module in Drupal 7. How could do that when the user logs in redirect to the home page ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest two options. You could use [Login redirect module](https://www.drupal.org/project/login_redirect) or you could use [Rules module](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) and set a rule reacting to event *user login* and performs *page redirect* action. If you want, you can also filter the redirection destination by role adding a condition to the rule